# Python/Pandas data frame time data in rows (grouped by name)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts

I have a data frame in Pandas that is like this:

```
Name Date       Value
A    2020-09-30 7.82
A    2020-04-22 3.23
A    2020-02-01 1.34
B    2020-09-30 8.89
B    2020-09-01 4.56
C    2020-09-30 9.56
C    2020-03-30 8.23
```

And the goal is to create a graph where the different values of each name's value is plotted on a timeline graph. So, for example, A will have 3 values on the chart mapped according to the date it had those values.

I tried the following:

```
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df.groupby('Name')['Value'].plot(legend=True)
```

However, the graph doesn't plot correctly, with the latest date to the left instead of the right. Also, since some Name's might have up to 5 Values and others only have up to 3, the graph doesn't seem to handle this very well. Finally, the data goes all the way from A to Z with a lot of entries and as such the above code creates an unreadable chart.

I am seeking guidance so I can better understand what approaches in Python/Pandas will work for this type of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely because your `Date` is string type, not datetime type; so Pandas/Matplotlib will just plot by the range index and label the data as the order the data shows up.

To fix the issue, just convert the `Date` to `datetime` type. Also, you can pass `figsize` option to `plot` so you can get a bigger plot:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df.groupby('Name')['Value'].plot(legend=True, marker='o', figsize=(10,6))
```

Output:

[image]